# Bugzilla workflow status restriction for normal user

Tags: linux, bugzilla

I have configured bugzilla 5 which have admin and normal users. In bug forms, in status field, I want to show some chosen statuses to normal user. so that can be restricted from doing actions they are not authorized like.

For example - normal user can resolve a bug but can not close it.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible in Bugzilla. The workflow editor does not allow you to specify a role.
There are some limited roles - canconfirm, editbugs but they apply to all bugs in the product.

You could create a Bugzilla extension that added this functionality. https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/integrating/extensions.html